# Correctly Setting Spatial Reference for Geometry Objects when Geoprocessing

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, coordinate-system

I'm attempting to find the nearest distance between a set of points, and a set of polygons. I don't want to use near tables because I have to do this operation for a large number of different selections on my polygon file, and I don't want to generate that many tables - all I need is a number. I'm trying to do this using geometry objects and the distanceTo() method, and storing a variable that keeps the smallest value for distanceTo(). In the end, it should just give me a single number: the shortest distance.

My problem so far has to do with spatial references *I think*. My point file is in UTM, and my polygon file is in state plane. Originally, the numbers I was getting were too large - millions of feet apart. So, I grabbed the spatial reference from my point file, and inserted it into both of my geometry objects when using the searchCursor. But now the numbers being returned are all 0 - and I know that my points don't *all* intersect.

I also know that all my selections on the polygon file are working properly - I've checked them ad nauseum - so I really don't think I'm getting erroneous numbers because of that.

So, my question is, have I entered the spatial references correctly? And if so, what else could be causing this issue? Is there something (there are probably many things...) that I don't understand about the distanceTo() tool?

```
shortestDistance = 10000000

pointFile = r"c:\data\points"
desc = arcpy.Describe(pointFile)
sr = desc.spatialReference

polyFile = r"c:\data\polys"
#these files get turned into feature layers
#in order to perform spatial selections
#and attribute queries

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polyFile, ["SHAPE@"], spatial_reference=sr):
    for part in row[0]:
        for pnt in part:
            if pnt:
                x = pnt.X
                y = pnt.Y
                point = arcpy.Point(x, y)
                array.add(point)   
            else:
                arcpy.AddMessage("Polygon with Interior Ring")

    vegPoly = arcpy.Polygon(array)

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pointFile, ["SHAPE@XY"], spatial_reference=sr):
    #make it a point geom
    x, y = row[0]
    point = arcpy.Point(x, y)
    centroid = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)

    distance = centroid.distanceTo(vegPoly)


    if distance < shortestDistance:
        shortestDistance = distance
```

Comment: Save yourself some grief and project them to a common coordinate system.  PS you need to put an r in front of your path names r'c:\temp\somefile.shp' or use double \\ or single / for path names

Comment: does assigning a spatial reference not reproject/transform the coordinates? i'll edit that "r" in. It's there in the actual code, i just threw in the generic stuff to avoid posting a wall of code.

Comment: You have to assign the spatial reference it is...not what you want it to be.  I would just use the Project tool to project one of them to match the other, then use the code.  It is important to use a spatial reference object, since without it, calculations have been documented to be in single precision.  Set your big number to a really big number not just one that is close to the biggest expected difference.  If in doubt, whip in a few print statements so you can see what 'distance' is yielding.

Comment: Got it. i'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: @DanPatterson Thanks, that did the trick. And thank you for clarifying the use of a spatial reference with the search cursor. If you put you answer in the answer box I'll gladly accept it.